# Spacing problem in Java program that prints tree as output

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Java method that prints a Christmas tree after taking two parameters: the number of segments and the height of each segment. It is supposed to have the following output with the number of segments set to 3 and the height of each segment set to 4:

```
     *            
    ***          
   *****        
  *******      
    ***       
   *****         
  *******       
 *********     
   *****      
  *******    
 *********       
***********
```

I was unable to figure it out as I had never tried to create for loops where each loop is affected by two variables and not just one. Hence, I looked up the solution online and found this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfSegments; i++) {
 for (int j = 1; j <= height; j++) {
      for (int k = 1; k <= ((numberOfSegments - i) + (height - j)); k++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int k = 1; k <= ((2 * j - 1) + (2 * i - 2)); k++) {
          System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
      }
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how they came up with the formula in the for loop that prints the spaces. I understand that each 'line' in a specific segment (among the 3 in this example) brings down the number of spaces by 1, and each subsequent segment also brings down the number of spaces by 1. But they subtracted i and j respectively from the variables numberOfSegments and height. Additionally, it's the stringing of the formula that's confusing me. How does it rationally follow that you are supposed to ADD the two variables after subtracting and i and j from each of them? And why is it that the variables numberOfSegments and height have no multiplier before them, such as (2 * numberOfSegments) or something similar? Please explain what my thought process should be if I tried to come up with the same formula. Or if you have a better formula that can be used here, do provide, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind this loop, specifically for the image you drew, is that `height` represents not the height of the tree, but of a single segment of it. In this case, that's 4. `numberOfSegments` is 3.

In your first loop, `i` goes from `1` up to and including `numberOfSegments`, so, it'll loop 3 times (once for each segment). `(numberOfSegments - i)` is that a simple way to reverse your counter. The first loop, that's `3 - 1` - so, `2`, next time it's 1, then 0. So, `i` counts `1, 2, 3`, and `(numberOfSegments - i)` counts `2, 1, 0`.

The same applies to `height - j`. `j` counts `1, 2, 3, 4`, and `height - j` counts `3, 2, 1, 0`.

For any given single line of your tree, the total # of stars you want to see depends on both the exact iteration of the height loop (for example, in the first segment, first time it's 1 star, second time 3, third time 5, fourth time 7) - looking at *solely* that segment, the first time through you need 3 spaces extra compared to the last time, which 0.

I suggest you leave nOfSegments at 1 for a while until you understand how just the height code works. Once you follow that, add numberOfSegments back in, it's just an extension of the same principle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Makes the function of the i and j subtractions clear, however I'm still confused as to their purpose. Why are we doing it? And why are we adding the two variables after subtracting? Also, each additional segment add two asterisks to each line, which part of the code addresses that and how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``i`` is the number of segments. ``j`` is the number of lines in each specific segment. My suggestion is to write the variables on a piece of paper, and follow the code, updating the variables as they change.

Comment: @johnzenten because the number of spaces you need in front of the stars depends on that. If you have a single segment and a height of 4, the final line has 7 stars. That means the line above it has 1 space and 5 stars. The # of spaces needed depends on how far we are 'away from the end', thus, the count-down, not the count-up. Same principle applies to an entire segment (it needs spaces because a segment below it has more stars).